Azure App Service cannot connect to Azure App Configuration with Private Endpoint?
I have a Java application hosted via Azure App Service and it uses Azure App Configuration to retrieve the connection strings and other details.
Recently, I had to disable public access to the Azure App Configuration and create a Private Endpoint for it.
Now, my application is not able to retrieve the data from the Azure App Configuration.
I made sure that the App Service and Azure App Configuration are under the same Virtual Network. I added the VNET range into the App Service networking rules. Updated the inbound rules for NSG to allow the VNET range.
Running the application locally gives the following error - com.azure.core.exception.HttpResponseException: Status code 403, (empty body) . I am assuming this error indicates it is not able to resolve the app configuration endpoint.
Doing all this still doesn't work for me. I am new to the networking aspect and any help would be appreciated. How can I make sure the App Service is able to connect to App Configuration?

Spontaneously it sounds like its either a DNS issue or an authentication issue.
Start looking at the connectivity with the service from within the VNet. Then once that is confirmed and you still get 403 look at how you have set up AuthN and AuthZ on the service (RBAC on IAM blade).
Connectivity:
Make sure you have a Private DNS Zone called privatelink.azconfig.io linked to your VNet with a record for Your-store-name pointing to the IP of the NW interface of the private endpoint also created in your resource group.
I would consider disabling the NSG entirely while troubleshooting (although I'm pretty sure that the inbound rules of the NSG are not at play at all here - this is an outbound issue. Have you looked at the outbound rules?).
As a troubleshooting tool I would recommend deploying a VM to your Vnet and use that to try to reach the App Config service from within the network, for example by doing doing nslookup and then also try to reach the https endpoint of App Configuration (https://{store-name}.azconfig.io). When you have the VM deployed you can also use Connection Troubleshoot in Azure Network Watcher.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-private-endpoint

Hi @Andreas,
I have done the same for one other application as well and it worked in case of that application. I recreated the Private endpoint with Private DNS zone enabled. Now, the applications keeps spinning eventually resulting in 503 Gateway timeout.
